# Executing python script with zmq from C# using IronPython not working

Tags: c#, python, zeromq, ironpython

I'm using ZeroMQ for inter-process communication between C# managed application and python script. When calling script from C#, using IronPython I get following error :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   **`IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException`** occurred in
>   Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
>
> Additional information: **cannot import constants from**
>   **`zmq.backend.cython`**

Python code (test.py file):

```
import sys, zmq, time

def execute(input):
    context = zmq.Context()

    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:18800")
    time.sleep(1)

    publisher.send(input) #just echo input parameter
```

And this is how I execute .py code from my C# app :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    options["Frames"] = true;
    options["FullFrames"] = true;

    ScriptEngine _engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
    ScriptRuntime _runtime = _engine.Runtime;
    ICollection<string> _searchPaths = _engine.GetSearchPaths();

    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\");
    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\");
    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Scripts\");
    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\libs\");
    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\DLLs\");
    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\include\");
    _searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages");

    _engine.SetSearchPaths(_searchPaths);

    dynamic wrapperObj = _runtime.UseFile("test.py");
    wrapperObj.execute("test");
}
```

Note that some code is omitted for brevity, and not actually relevant for this scenario. When manually invoking .py script through the command line, everything works fine, I'm able to pass data around and my C# app is receiving messages.

Anyone knows what is this error and how can be solved?

---

**`EDIT :`** While I was desperate and almost gave up, I tried to write quick named-pipes support, and guess what - similar error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>  **`IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException`** occurred in
>   Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
>
> Additional information: No module named win32file

This time, my test.py looks like this:

```
import win32file

def execute(input):
    handle = win32file.CreateFile(r"\\.\pipe\test_pipe",
                                   win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                   0, None,
                                   win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                   0, None)

    if handle:
        win32file.WriteFile(self.handle, input, None)
        win32file.FlushFileBuffers(self.handle)
        win32file.SetFilePointer(self.handle, 0, win32file.FILE_BEGIN)
```

I'm not really sure if I have more options for this kind of interoperability, but I'm starting to think that IronPython can just cover basic usage scenarios (when calling pure python code from C#), not to mention **`matplotlib`**, **`numpy`** or **`astropy`** that I will certanly need later on.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Civa

Comment: Do you indeed need IronPython form of embedding the python-side services? ZeroMQ is wonderfull framework for designing fully distributed processing systems, so why not having all your tools and imports ready in a standalone python ( or self-scaleable cluster of processing nodes, as needed ) and making all the integration signalling + messaging work via ZeroMQ transports?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will consider that. Anyway, I think I will need some sort of python-C# interoperability, which obviously has many limitations using IronPython.